# Latex: \footnote command not working in solution environment of exam package

Tags: footnotes, exam

I'm using exam package, I would like to add a footnote to a solution: it displays the mark but not the note text. In question environment it is all right.

```
\documentclass[12pt, answers]{exam}
%\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[english, italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{footnote}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Risposta:}\enspace}

\newcommand{\col}[1]{{\color[rgb]{0.094,0.235,0.36}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myt}[1]{\textbf{\col{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myhdr}[4]{
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheader{\myt{#1}}{\Huge\myt{#2}}{\myt{#3}}
\runningheader{\myt{#1}}{\Huge\myt{#2}}{\myt{#3}}
\firstpagefooter{}{\myt{#2}}{\myt{#4}}
\runningfooter{}{\myt{#2}}{\myt{#4}}
\runningfootrule
}


%\myhdr{3A - INT}{Domande da un minuto}{Sistemi}{Pag. \thepage\ - \numpages}
\checkboxchar{$\Box$}


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\section{Capitolo 1}
\subsection{Quizzes}


\subsection{Questions}
\question
In quali parti si divide un \footnote{footnotes working fine} indirizzo IPv4?
    \begin{solution}Network portion e Host portion\footnote{footnotes working fine} \end{solution}


\section{Capitolo 8}
\subsection{Quizzes}
\subsection{Questions}
\question
In quanti livelli viene, di fatto, divisa la gerarchia della rete dal momento in cui aggiungo le sottoreti?
    \begin{solution}Tre: rete, sottorete e host\end{solution}
\question
Che cosa viene facilitato dalla creazione di un ulteriore livello nella gerarchia di rete?
    \begin{solution}La creazione dei sottogruppi nella rete IP che ne deriva facilita la velocizzazione di trasmissione dei pacchetti e la minimizzazione del traffico locale\footnote{8.0.1.1: Introducing an additional level to the hierarchy creates additional sub-groups within an IP network that facilitates faster packet delivery and added filtration, by helping to minimize ‘local’ traffic.}\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have it working even with my footer on, though commented in this example.

Comment: Follow-up Question: [Latex: how to get question number in exam package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392593/4301).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `footnote` pacakge to obtain footnotes from within the `exam` class:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, answers]{exam}

\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{solution}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question
Some question
\begin{solution} 
    Text\footnote{Some footnote} 
\end{solution}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Anyway, just using package footnote was of no help, until I added the \makesavenoteenv{solution} line. Could you please explain the little magic of that command?

Comment: @massi: The `\makesavenoteenv` is used to specify for which environments, the `\footnotes` should be saved.

Comment: It works, but it has a problem. When the answer option is removed, the footnote still appears in the document.

Comment: @SergioLlorente: I think it best if you ask a new question and include a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.  You can reference this question if it is relevant.

Comment: I wasn't getting the footnote text even for footnotes outside of solution environments. So to expand on @PeterGrill's comment, you can turn them on everywhere with `\makesavenoteenv{questions}` (though for some reason `\makesavenoteenv{document}` doesn't work).

Comment: Actually, `\makesavenoteenv{questions}` isn't a good option, because it throws the footnote to the page when the `questions` environment ends. I ended up putting the paragraph containing my footnote into a full-width minipage, and used `\makesavenoteenv{minipage}` with success.

Answer (score 0):

I use endnotes (with the enotez package) in this context, and it seems to work smoothly. When I just want the exam without solutions, I comment out the \printendnotes line at the end to not display the endnotes at all.

Comment: This seems better-suited as a comment, as it provides an alternative approach to `\footnote`s rather than solving the problem.