# Latex: how to get question number in exam package

Tags: footnotes, exam

I am using exam package and I would like to add an extension to some solution in the form of a footnote with the same number of the question, as in

```
\documentclass[12pt, answers]{exam}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Risposta:}\enspace}
\checkboxchar{$\Box$}


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\section{Capitolo 1}
\question
which question am I?
\begin{solution}One \end{solution}

\question
which question am I, instead?
\begin{solution}Two \end{solution}

\question
How do I get the question current number?
    \begin{solution} Three \footnote[\questionnumber]{I would like this footnote to be numbered the same as the question} \end{solution}

\end{questions}


\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the footnote would not show up at all (as noticed in [Latex: \footnote command not working in solution environment of exam package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392573/latex-footnote-command-not-working-in-solution-environment-of-exam-package)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend of mine gave me a quicker and simpler solution "live", so I'm reporting it:

```
\documentclass[12pt, answers]{exam}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Risposta:}\enspace}
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{solution}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\section{Capitolo 1}
\question
which question am I?
\begin{solution}One \end{solution}

\question
which question am I, instead?
\begin{solution}Two \end{solution}

\question
How do I get the question current number?
    \begin{solution} Three \footnote[\thequestiontitle]{I would like this footnote to be numbered the same as the question} \end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

According to package documentation ([http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/examdoc.pdf](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Epsh/exam/examdoc.pdf)) at page 31

> \thequestiontitle (see section 4.5.2), which expands to
>
> ...
>
> – the number of the question, if this question was defined using a \question command

Answer (score 5):

Exam uses the counter `question` for questions.

```
\documentclass[12pt, answers]{exam}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Risposta:}\enspace}
\checkboxchar{$\Box$}

\newcommand*\countoff[1]% #1 = counter name
{\ifcase\value{#1}{??}\or{One}\or{Two}\or{Three}\or{Four}\or{Five}%
   \or{Six}\or{Seven}\or{Eight}\or{Nine}\or{Ten}% ad infinitum
 \else{??}%
 \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\section{Capitolo 1}
\question
which question am I?
\begin{solution}\thequestion \end{solution}

\question
which question am I, instead?
\begin{solution}\arabic{question} \end{solution}

\question
How do I get the question current number?
    \begin{solution}\countoff{question} \footnote[\thequestion]{I would like this footnote to be numbered the same as the question} \end{solution}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the usual `\label`/`\ref` mechanism. Since it is being used in a `\footnote` you need to expand it first. I do this with an `\xdef` below:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, answers]{exam}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Risposta:}\enspace}
\checkboxchar{$\Box$}

%% Need this to get footnote from within the exam class.
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392622/4301
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{solution}

\newcommand{\ExamFootnote}[2]{%
    %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50111/4301
    \xdef\currentQuestion{\ref{#1}}%
    \ifnum0<0\currentQuestion\else
        \def\currentQuestion{0}%
    \fi
    \footnote[\currentQuestion]{#2}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\section{Capitolo 1}
\question
    which question am I?
\begin{solution}
One 
\end{solution}

\question\label{question:This Question}
which question am I, instead?
\begin{solution}
    Two\ExamFootnote{question:This Question}{foot note for 2}
\end{solution}

\question\label{question:That Question}
How do I get the question current number?
\begin{solution} 
    Three \ExamFootnote{question:That Question}{I would like this footnote to be numbered the same as the question} 
\end{solution}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer is exactly the solution to my problem... But compiling your code generates errors : Illegal parameter number in definition of \currentQuestion :/

Comment: Without a complete  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that reproduces the error it is difficlut to diagnose. I suggest you post a new question including a  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301). You can reference this question if it is relevant.