# Footnotes in solution environment of exam package

Tags: footnotes, exam

Two years ago I found this solution for including footnotes in the solution environment of the exam package:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392622/96422

This answer propose to use the footnote package, and it works perfectly, but it has a problem: when the answer option is removed, the footnote still appears in the document, as you can see modifying the same example given in the referenced answer:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{solution}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question
Some question
\begin{solution} 
    Text\footnote{Some footnote that must not appear when answers option is 
    removed} 
\end{solution}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

That means that you have to comment out each footnote to set up an exam without solutions. I would like the footnotes in the solutions to only show when `answers` options is given.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution using other commands in footnote package: `\savenotes` and `\spewnotes`. They enclose a group where the footnotes are saved and executed at the end. They can be used only when answers are being printed with  the boolean `\ifprintanswers` defined by exam class:

```
\documentclass[12pt,answers]{exam}
%\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\usepackage{footnote}
%\makesavenoteenv{solution}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question
Some question
\ifprintanswers
\savenotes 
\fi
\begin{solution}
    Text\footnote{Some footnote that must not appear when answers option is 
    removed} 
\end{solution}
\ifprintanswers
\spewnotes
\fi

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

It may be worthy to redefine the `TheSolution` enviroment of the exam package to include those commands (based on the original code of [exam.cls](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam)):

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{TheSolution}%
  {%
    \savenotes%
    \vspace{\parskip}%
    % If we don't set \leftskip and \rightskip to 0pt, then if we
    % appear inside of an \uplevel command we'd have indentation
    % inside of the solution box:
    \leftskip=0pt
    \rightskip=0pt
    % If the user said \unframedsolutions, then both
    % \if@framedsolutions and \if@shadedsolutions are false:
    \if@framedsolutions
      % We'll use the default \exam@FrameCommand
    \else
      \if@shadedsolutions
        \def\exam@FrameCommand{\colorbox{SolutionColor}}%
      \else
        % It's \unframedsolutions:
        \def\exam@FrameCommand{}%
      \fi
    \fi
    \exam@MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\exam@width}%
    \solutiontitle
    \ignorespaces
  }%
  {%
    \unskip
    \endexam@MakeFramed
    \spewnotes
  }%
\makeatother
```

A possible problem is that if footnotes are used in the question statements, there will be jumps in the numbering of those footnotes when the answers are not printed.

Comment: Use symbols? († ‡ ⸸ ⸶ ⸷).